# 39 GB Log files !! What's going on.?

Tags: disk, disk-usage, logs

I have log files located under `/var/logs` those sizes are around `40 GB`. Space is running out .

How to delete the log files without affecting the normal operation?

Those files are locked. What is the procedure to unlock the files?

And how simple log files became such gigantic disk eaters.?

Help me please.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo rm $(find /var/log -name '*.gz') -rf
```

clears the compressed old log files or you may try **bleachbit** application. But you must find what causes this.

Comment: I cant execute the command because Terminal reports that the permission is denied.  Any ideas ?

Comment: I think I should now format entire the system ( except Windows) . Because there are much more really weird problems. I have no UI for many applications, system hangs and blinks during startup,sometimes screen resolution is being changed automatically. I think some hardware issues or driver related issues are present. Inside the sound indicator located on the top of he system,it appears like ouput volume is being decreased and increased often.As a result sound is imperfect and I have to plug-in a headphone make the sound steady.

Comment: This computer is actually an old  HP Compaq PC with Foxconn MBoard and HP branded PSU . But the Board was dead a few months ago and 
I replaced it with Gigabyte board  but didn't spend money on buying a new PSU , instead I used the old PSU. The  repairman was mentioned that this old PSU is actually not well suited for this Board but we both had no interest  in investing more money in this old PC.  So we just used it . Now I think due to PSU , there are problems.

Comment: I cant install Bleachbit , because Software Center is running without any UI , or even though there is a UI ,  I got no space to install it. 0 bytes free.

Comment: what exactly terminal says when you try to execute the command?

Comment: lol i understand now. You have no space left on the root partition. It would be  better  boot system with an external usb and delete files manually from there.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what the reasons are for the accumulation of so many or large log files. You should maybe consider filing a bug.

I do not recommend deleting system files whose function you do not understand (they are locked for a reason), so try the following methods at your own risk.

**1. Command line.** If you would like to delete the older log files in that directory, enter the following command in a Terminal window:

```
sudo rm /var/logs/*.gz *.1 *.old
```

**2. File Manager.** You can choose what files to delete on the file manager launching **nautilus** (assuming you use Unity) with root privileges. This way you could try to identify what files are the problem and report them. Make sure you only remove older files like the ones specified above:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Comment: To be honest just simply deleting the main log files will break more than solve anything.

Comment: Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Improve it, whats fair game for deletion is, files ending in `.gz`, `.1`, `.old`. But never simply delete the normal log files, it will cause all kind of unwanted symptoms.

Comment: Thank you, I just did. I need more judgement to answer some questions.

Answer (score 0):

Most files located in /var/log should be rotated by logrotate.
see: man logrotate

```
LOGROTATE(8)                                                             System Administrator's Manual                                                            LOGROTATE(8)

NAME
       logrotate - rotates, compresses, and mails system logs
...
```

You should be able to remove *.1 and/or *.gz with:

```
find /var/log \( -name "*.[0-9]" -o -name "*.gz" \) -delete
```

If you are not sure if a file is in use, you can check the state with

```
fuser
```

or with

```
lsof -Pn|grep
```

If it is in use and you want to "clear" it, never delete the file ! The file system will not be freed if a file is in use.
To clear a "in use" file and free up space use the command:

```
echo -n >filename
```

or just

```
>filename
```

If files getting very big the most reason is: debugging-flag set in some configuration or http-logfiles. Just check the big file(s) with "fuser" to get the PID of the owning process. Clear it with "echo" or do a "tail -50" (if no PID is found with fuser) to check who is writing the log files to reconfigure the chattiness of the application. Or you can add a logrotate configuration for this file to "clear" it after 24hours for example.

Comment: But  I accidentally deleted all the contents of logs folder and the system went hanging all the time. So I had to reinstall. But still there are problems. I assume graphics driver have issues. I had to find a way to install it . Intel mobile GM45

Answer (score 0):

I think I should now format entire the system ( except Windows) . Because there are much more really weird problems. I have no UI for many applications, system hangs and blinks during startup,sometimes screen resolution is being changed automatically. I think some hardware issues or driver related issues are present. Inside the sound indicator located on the top of he system,it appears like ouput volume is being decreased and increased often.As a result sound is imperfect and I have to plug-in a headphone make the sound steady.

This computer is actually an old HP Compaq PC with Foxconn MBoard and HP branded PSU . But the Board was dead a few months ago and I replaced it with Gigabyte board but didn't spend money on buying a new PSU , instead I used the old PSU. The repairman was mentioned that this old PSU is actually not well suited for this Board but we both had no interest in investing more money in this old PC. So we just used it . Now I think due to PSU , there are problems

Comment: Oh !!! I did a serious mistake. I ran Nautilus as SU and removed everything located under the log folder. 

As a result, now the system is almost instable and frequently freezes. 

Now only way is reinstallation or is there any still any solutions?

I ran Ubuntu with Linux and tried several repairs. Still no way.

Comment: Please dont use here like a forum. I just warn you but others may be more cruel by voting you minus because non-answer posts doesn't accepted like this one. It is better to delete them and post these as a comment to your question. (:

Comment: Oh. Ok.. I just thought to highlight what I have to tell. I didn't know about that. Thanks for letting me know this.

Answer (score 0):

Oh !!! I did a serious mistake. I ran Nautilus as SU and removed everything located under the log folder.

As a result, now the system is almost instable and frequently freezes.

Now only way is reinstallation or is there any still any solutions?

I ran Ubuntu with Linux and tried several repairs. Still no way.